# Decreasing rearrangement function for the functions of measure space $X$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, metric-spaces

Let $f : R^{+} \ to R $ be a real measurable function on $R^{+} = [0; \infty)$ and let $$ \eta_{|f|}(y) = m\{|f| \gt y\} \in [0; \infty] \: \: \: \:y \in R^{+}$$ be the distribution function of the absolute value |f|.

Note that : $\{f > y\} := \{ x \in R^{+} \: : f(x) > y \}, \: y \in R^{+}$

Since the function $\eta_{|f|}$ is decreasing and right-continuous, it has a unique generalized inverse, which is also decreasing and right-continuous. This inverse function $\eta^{-1}_{|f|}$ will be denoted by $f^{*}$, and it has the form  $$ f^{*}(x) = \inf\{y \geq 0 : \eta_{|f|}(y) \leq x \} $$. The function $f^{*}$ is called a decreasing rearrangement of the function $|f|$.

We also know that the functions $f^{*}$ and $|f|$ are equimeasurable.

Note that : Nonnegative functions $f$ and $g$ are called equimeasurable if $\eta_f = \eta_g$ .

There is my question: Let $X$ be a separable metric space with a Borel regular outer measure $\mu^{*}$ such that $\mu X = 1 $.

For example: Consider space $L^{p}(X,\mu)$ Let $f$ be any function of $L^{p}(X,\mu)$  which maps X in the space of real numbers. ( I mean we don't have specified  range) $\eta_{f}(y) = \mu\{f > y \} $ and $\{f > y \} = \{ x \in X : f(x) > y\} $, and $f^{*}(x) = \inf\{y \geq 0 : \eta_{|f|}(y) \leq x \}$. but how can we compare $\eta_{|f|}$ to $x$ ?
$x$ is not real number necessarily, while $\eta_{|f|}$ is. This is the problem which emerges.
How can I define something like a decreasing rearrangement function for the functions of space $X$, which satisfies these conditions.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me elaborate on Iván P.'s answer. If $(X,\mathcal B,\mu)$ is a measure space and $f\colon X\to \mathbb R$ a measurable function. The distribution function of $|f|$ is defined exactly as in the case described in the question, namely
$$
\eta_{|f|}\colon [0,\infty)\to [0,\infty],\,\eta_{|f|}(y)=\mu(\{|f|>y\}).
$$
Note that if $f\in L^p(X,\mu)$ for $p<\infty$, then $\eta_{|f|}(y)<\infty$ for $y>0$.

But now we are exactly in the situation described in the question: The function $\eta_{|f|}$ is decreasing and right-continuous, and we can define the decreasing rearrangement of $f$ by
$$
f^\ast\colon [0,\infty)\to [0,\infty],\,f^\ast(x)=\inf\{y\geq 0\mid \eta_{|f|}(y)\leq x\}.
$$
So, as Iván said, you really just copy the definition.

Comment: But $x \in X$ measure space. How can you compare $\eta_{|f|}(y)$ to $x \in X$ ? $x$ couldn’t be a real number.

Comment: That's why I explicitly wrote the domain of all maps. $f^\ast$ is defined on $[0,\infty)$, not on $X$!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can just copy the definition changing the Lebesgue measure $m$ with the measure $\mu$.

You can check out the book

Grafakos, "Classical Fourier Analysis"; section 1.4.1 "Decreasing rearrengements".

Comment: can you tell me the exact page?

Comment: You can not just copy it because you don't have numbers necessarily in Measure space.

Comment: What's maybe not quite clear from this answer is that the distribution function and the decreasing rearrangement of a measurable function on $X$ will still be functions on $\mathbb R_+$, not on $X$. That being said, Iván P. is right: You can just copy your definitions.

Comment: @MaoWao Measure is a number. how can you assume that number is less  or equal to the $x \in X$ ? the elements of space $X$ are not necessarily numbers.

Comment: I thought you are talking about functions from $X$ to $\mathbb R$. Do you mean functions from $X$ to $X$ instead?

Comment: @MaoWao Not necessarily. It could be other space where numbers are not defined. How can you compare number ( which is measure of something) to a different object, assuming it is function from X to X

Comment: @MaoWao Consider space $L^{p}(X,\mu)$ Let $f$ be any function of $L^{p}(X,\mu)$  which maps X anywhere. ( I mean we don't have specified  range) $\eta_{f}(y) = \mu\{f > y \} $ and $\{f > y \} = \{ x \in X : f(x) > y $, but we can't guaranteed compare $f(x)$ to the real number $y$, because $f(x)$ couldn't be a number.

Comment: I edited the question and read it please.

Comment: The space $L^p(X,\mu)$ is usually defined as space of real- or complex-valued functions. You could also take Banach-valued functions. In any case, the function $|f|$ takes values in $\mathbb R_+$. So it is not clear to me what your setup is if you object to Iván's answer.

Comment: @MaoWao I have edited it again. Even in this case when we take mapping from $X$ to $R$, this problem emerges. I think now you would get the gist of my question. Please read it.